# Feathersjs filter results

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I have created a node/feathers project using [this chat application guide](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/chat/readme.html) as a base. It's working great, but now I would like to filter the results the api is giving. For example, when user makes GET request to /messages I would like the response to include only the messages that the authorized user has created, not anyone else's messages. Auth is working correctly in the api and message items have the userId who created the message, but I just don't understand what and where I'm supposed to do to filter the messages according to the user id. After hours of googling I couldn't find anything related to this or anyone even asking the question, so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a manual filtering. Both on `before` and `after` hooks. [How to use hooks](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html).

In before hooks you can create a function that update your query object to only get/find data it owns.

```
hook.params.query = { ... , ownedBy: hook.params.user._id }
```

Or do result filtering in after hooks, you have the `hook.result` which is the only thing you can manipulate in the after hooks. Then you can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example) to filter the results the user gets.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I also realised there is an authentication hook restrictToOwner that can also be used for this purpose.